# How to return some error instead of page saving in wagtail?

Tags: python, wagtail

I have this `wagtail` page model:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
...
class PhotoEventPage(Page):
    photos = models.FileField()
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('photos'),
        FieldPanel('description')
    ]
```

And I want not to save this page when `photos` extension is not `zip`, so i want to display an error in wagtail admin in this case. So I've tried:

```
class PhotoEventPage(Page):
    photos = models.FileField()
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('photos'),
        FieldPanel('description')
    ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.photos.file.name.split('.')[-1] != 'zip':
            return ValidationError('test')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it doesn't work, maybe anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried overriding form `clean` method?

Comment: yes, i will, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom form for the page, and add your validation logic in a `clean` method there:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *gasman*. As said in docs I need to set `base_form_class` on the model:

```
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm


class PhotoEventPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        if (cleaned_data.get('photos') and
                cleaned_data['photos'].name.split('.')[-1] != 'zip'):
            self.add_error('photos', 'Расширение должно быть zip')

        return cleaned_data


class PhotoEventPage(Page):
    photos = models.FileField()
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('photos'),
        FieldPanel('description')
    ]
    base_form_class = PhotoEventPageForm
```